# Define our own type as a value type in c#. What about it's storage location?

Tags: c#

I think we can use a Struct type for that, but I don't know how can C# consider that as a value type, can anyone give a confirmation for that or an example

> So is there a case where a value type is stored on the Heap and a reference type in the stack ?

Thank's

Comment: An easy circumstance that would put a value type on the heap is when it's a class member of a reference type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are objects that are stored by reference and structs are stored by value. The referenced classes are stored on the `heap` (the large pool of memory in your RAM) and the structs are stored on the `stack`, which is a small portion of memory reserved for your application. This resource is limited and you should not abuse of structs if they are not needed.

Comment: There is no guarantee that reference types are stored in the heap or that value types are stored on the stack.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx  Reference variables that are part of a closure are likely on the heap.  Some reference variables might even be JITed as CPU registers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, struct is a [value type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) in C#.

> A struct type is a value type that is typically used to encapsulate small groups of related variables, such as the coordinates of a rectangle or the characteristics of an item in an inventory

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx

As an interesting aside, there is a common misconception that reference variables are always allocated on the heap and value types always on the stack.  Eric Lippert points out that [The Stack is an Implementation Detail](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx).